# Success function not working based on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax call that is working, but the success function isn't. I have a a few dates that I am inputting, after hitting submit, there should be a little alert popup saying "Data saved to the DB". The data is getting saved to the DB, however I am not getting the popup alert window.

```
$("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {
                createUpdateArrays();
                var url = "/Sample/Selection";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    data: { ids: ids, dates: dates },
                    success: function (success) {
                        if (success === true) {
                            alert("Success");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });

                ids = "";
                dates = "";
            });
            function createUpdateArrays() {
                var i = 0;
                $('input.remedy-id:checkbox').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        var rid = $(this).attr("id");
                        $('.planned-date').each(function () {
                            var did = $(this).attr("id");
                            if (did === rid) {
                                var date = $(this).val();
                                ids += rid + ",";
                                dates += date + ",";
                            }
                        });
                    };
                });
            };
```

I can't seem to understand the reason behind this..

Comment: your success function contains an if condition, are you returning a boolean value from your ajax call, if not remove the if condition and directly show alert

Comment: To add to @YashSoni input, do you know exactly what `success` is? Might be insightful to do a `console.log("success response: ", success)` in your success callback function.

Comment: i know , but success method returns some data, in this case its function(success), and if condition is applied here, so is the data returned from success function a boolean or just a mistake, so remove the IF CONDITION from success method and display popup directly

Comment: Even after removing the if statement and displaying the popup directly, the code never reaches that point..

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Before doing **ANYTHING** else, make sure that your server is actually returning a response to begin with.

Your success function is expecting a boolean to be returned by the server, but this is probably not what is happening. If you're returning a simple string "success" from the server, then the comparison should be `if (success === "success")`. This is entirely dependent on what your server is returning as a response.

Perhaps your server is returning a status code of 2xx. In either case, you can use the jQuery status code callbacks:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                data: { ids: ids, dates: dates },
                statusCode: {
                  200: function(){alert("Success!")},
                  201: function(){alert("Success!")}
                }
            });
```

And if you don't want to do that and just want to use the `success` callback, try something like this:

```
                    success: function (success) {
                        if (success || (success.length && success.length == 0)) { // this will almost definitely evaluate to true
                            console.log(success) // Do this to see what is actually being returned. I guarantee it isn't a boolean value.
                            alert("Success");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error. However, the data is being updated in the DB...

Comment: @caitlinp add a 500 to the statusCode options in jquery callback. But really, the 500 callback shouldn’t log success lol. Fix the internal server error and then return a 2xx response

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out... The server is up and running, the data is getting updated.. I don't know whats wrong lol

Comment: @caitlinp well you’re getting an internal server error, so your server side code after the data is inserted into the DB has an error in it.